# Realtime audio processing without output

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio

I'm looking on this example http://teragonaudio.com/article/How-to-do-realtime-recording-with-effect-processing-on-iOS.html

and i want to turn off my output. I try to change: `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord` to `kAudioSessionCategory_RecordAudio` but this is not working. I also try to get rid off:

```
  if(AudioUnitSetProperty(*audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                            kAudioUnitScope_Output, 1, &streamDescription, sizeof(streamDescription)) != noErr) {
        return 1;
    }
```

Becouse i want to get sound from microphone but not playing it. But not matter what i do when my sound get to renderCallback method there is a -50 error. When audio is automatically play on output everything works fine...

Update with code:

```
using namespace std;

AudioUnit *audioUnit = NULL;

float *convertedSampleBuffer = NULL;

int initAudioSession() {
    audioUnit = (AudioUnit*)malloc(sizeof(AudioUnit));

    if(AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) != noErr) {
        return 1;
    }

    if(AudioSessionSetActive(true) != noErr) {
        return 1;
    }

    UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
    if(AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                               sizeof(UInt32), &sessionCategory) != noErr) {
        return 1;
    }

    Float32 bufferSizeInSec = 0.02f;
    if(AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareIOBufferDuration,
                               sizeof(Float32), &bufferSizeInSec) != noErr) {
        return 1;
    }

    UInt32 overrideCategory = 1;
    if(AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker,
                               sizeof(UInt32), &overrideCategory) != noErr) {
        return 1;
    }

    // There are many properties you might want to provide callback functions for:
    // kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange
    // kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput
    // etc.

    return 0;
}

OSStatus renderCallback(void *userData, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *actionFlags,
                        const AudioTimeStamp *audioTimeStamp, UInt32 busNumber,
                        UInt32 numFrames, AudioBufferList *buffers) {
    OSStatus status = AudioUnitRender(*audioUnit, actionFlags, audioTimeStamp,
                                      1, numFrames, buffers);

    int doOutput = 0;

    if(status != noErr) {
        return status;
    }

    if(convertedSampleBuffer == NULL) {
        // Lazy initialization of this buffer is necessary because we don't
        // know the frame count until the first callback
        convertedSampleBuffer = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * numFrames);
        baseTime = (float)QRealTimer::getUptimeInMilliseconds();
    }

    SInt16 *inputFrames = (SInt16*)(buffers->mBuffers->mData);

    // If your DSP code can use integers, then don't bother converting to
    // floats here, as it just wastes CPU. However, most DSP algorithms rely
    // on floating point, and this is especially true if you are porting a
    // VST/AU to iOS.

    int i;

    for( i = numFrames; i < fftlength; i++ )        // Shifting buffer
        x_inbuf[i - numFrames] = x_inbuf[i];

    for(  i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
        x_inbuf[i + x_phase] = (float)inputFrames[i] / (float)32768;
    }

    if( x_phase + numFrames == fftlength )
    {
        x_alignment.SigProc_frontend(x_inbuf);  // Signal processing front-end (FFT!)
        doOutput = x_alignment.Align();


        /// Output as text! In the real-time version,
        //      this is where we update visualisation callbacks and launch other services
        if ((doOutput) & (x_netscore.isEvent(x_alignment.Position()))
            &(x_alignment.lastAction()<x_alignment.Position()) )
        {
          //  here i want to do something with my input!
        }
    }
    else
        x_phase += numFrames;


   return noErr;
}


int initAudioStreams(AudioUnit *audioUnit) {
    UInt32 audioCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
    if(AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                               sizeof(UInt32), &audioCategory) != noErr) {
        return 1;
    }

    UInt32 overrideCategory = 1;
    if(AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker,
                               sizeof(UInt32), &overrideCategory) != noErr) {
        // Less serious error, but you may want to handle it and bail here
    }

    AudioComponentDescription componentDescription;
    componentDescription.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    componentDescription.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    componentDescription.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    componentDescription.componentFlags = 0;
    componentDescription.componentFlagsMask = 0;
    AudioComponent component = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &componentDescription);
    if(AudioComponentInstanceNew(component, audioUnit) != noErr) {
        return 1;
    }

    UInt32 enable = 1;
    if(AudioUnitSetProperty(*audioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                            kAudioUnitScope_Input, 1, &enable, sizeof(UInt32)) != noErr) {
        return 1;
    }

    AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
    callbackStruct.inputProc = renderCallback; // Render function
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = NULL;
    if(AudioUnitSetProperty(*audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                            kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &callbackStruct,
                            sizeof(AURenderCallbackStruct)) != noErr) {
        return 1;
    }

    AudioStreamBasicDescription streamDescription;
    // You might want to replace this with a different value, but keep in mind that the
    // iPhone does not support all sample rates. 8kHz, 22kHz, and 44.1kHz should all work.
    streamDescription.mSampleRate = 44100;
    // Yes, I know you probably want floating point samples, but the iPhone isn't going
    // to give you floating point data. You'll need to make the conversion by hand from
    // linear PCM <-> float.
    streamDescription.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    // This part is important!
    streamDescription.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger |
    kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian |
    kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    streamDescription.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    // 1 sample per frame, will always be 2 as long as 16-bit samples are being used
    streamDescription.mBytesPerFrame = 2;
    streamDescription.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    streamDescription.mBytesPerPacket = streamDescription.mBytesPerFrame *
    streamDescription.mChannelsPerFrame;
    // Always should be set to 1
    streamDescription.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    // Always set to 0, just to be sure
    streamDescription.mReserved = 0;

    // Set up input stream with above properties
    if(AudioUnitSetProperty(*audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                            kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &streamDescription, sizeof(streamDescription)) != noErr) {
        return 1;
    }

    // Ditto for the output stream, which we will be sending the processed audio to
    if(AudioUnitSetProperty(*audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                            kAudioUnitScope_Output, 1, &streamDescription, sizeof(streamDescription)) != noErr) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}


int startAudioUnit(AudioUnit *audioUnit) {
    if(AudioUnitInitialize(*audioUnit) != noErr) {
        return 1;
    }

    if(AudioOutputUnitStart(*audioUnit) != noErr) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And calling from my VC:

```
  initAudioSession();
    initAudioStreams( audioUnit);
    startAudioUnit( audioUnit);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want only recording, no playback, simply comment out the line that sets renderCallback:

```
AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
callbackStruct.inputProc = renderCallback; // Render function
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = NULL;
if(AudioUnitSetProperty(*audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
   kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &callbackStruct,
   sizeof(AURenderCallbackStruct)) != noErr) {
  return 1;
}
```

Update after seeing code:

As I suspected, you're missing input callback. Add these lines:

```
// at top:
#define kInputBus 1

AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
/**/
callbackStruct.inputProc = &ALAudioUnit::recordingCallback;
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = this;
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit,
                              kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback,
                              kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                              kInputBus,
                              &callbackStruct,
                              sizeof(callbackStruct));
```

Now in your recordingCallback:

```
OSStatus ALAudioUnit::recordingCallback(void *inRefCon,
                                        AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                        const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                                        UInt32 inBusNumber,
                                        UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                        AudioBufferList *ioData)
{
    // TODO: Use inRefCon to access our interface object to do stuff
    // Then, use inNumberFrames to figure out how much data is available, and make
    // that much space available in buffers in an AudioBufferList.

    // Then:
    // Obtain recorded samples

    OSStatus status;

    ALAudioUnit *pThis = reinterpret_cast<ALAudioUnit*>(inRefCon);
    if (!pThis)
        return noErr;

    //assert (pThis->m_nMaxSliceFrames >= inNumberFrames);

    pThis->recorderBufferList->GetBufferList().mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * pThis->m_recorderSBD.mBytesPerFrame;

    status = AudioUnitRender(pThis->audioUnit,
                             ioActionFlags,
                             inTimeStamp,
                             inBusNumber,
                             inNumberFrames,
                             &pThis->recorderBufferList->GetBufferList());
    THROW_EXCEPTION_IF_ERROR(status, "error rendering audio unit");

    // If we're not playing, I don't care about the data, simply discard it
    if (!pThis->playbackState || pThis->isSeeking) return noErr;

    // Now, we have the samples we just read sitting in buffers in bufferList
    pThis->DoStuffWithTheRecordedAudio(inNumberFrames, pThis->recorderBufferList, inTimeStamp);

    return noErr;
}
```

Btw, I'm allocating my own buffer instead of using the one provided by AudioUnit. You might want to change those parts if you want to use AudioUnit allocated buffer.

Update:

How to allocate own buffer:

```
recorderBufferList = new AUBufferList();
recorderBufferList->Allocate(m_recorderSBD, m_nMaxSliceFrames);
recorderBufferList->PrepareBuffer(m_recorderSBD, m_nMaxSliceFrames);
```

Also, if you're doing this, tell AudioUnit to not allocate buffers:

```
// Disable buffer allocation for the recorder (optional - do this if we want to pass in our own)
flag = 0;
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit,
                              kAudioUnitProperty_ShouldAllocateBuffer,
                              kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                              kInputBus,
                              &flag,
                              sizeof(flag));
```

You'll need to include [CoreAudio utility classes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreAudioUtilityClasses/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: No, i need render input. I don't want to be played right away, but want render method. The issue here is to get sound from mic and modify it in real time. That's renderCallback do.

Comment: I don't understand. I thought you wanted only microphone input, no output. Do you want input/output and want to modify input in real time and send it to output?

Comment: I want modify input in real time, but don't send it to output. So i don't need output but need render method.

Comment: That line sets the callback for providing input to _output bus_. If you don't want to provide any input to output bus (that is, you don't want any output), don't specify this callback. You'll get microphone input data in the callback specified with kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback. I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: So what about render methods? How can i modify my input? When i do that my renderCallback method is never call.

Comment: Oooh i see it. One more question - what about inputProcRefCon? You set it to this. Why?

Comment: This is so I can reconstruct _this_ object later in recordingCallback. The first parameter _void *_ contains the value passed to inputProcRefCon.

Comment: Sorry - can you post also your own buffers? I have problems with Audio Unit ones. Always return null.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26954/discussion-between-simpleman-and-mar0ux)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @Mar0ux 's answer. Whoever got here looking for complete sample code doing this can take a look here:

https://code.google.com/p/ios-coreaudio-example/

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a similar app working with the same code and I found that you can end playback by changing the enumeration `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord` to `RecordAudio`

```
int initAudioStreams(AudioUnit *audioUnit) {
UInt32 audioCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_RecordAudio;
if(AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                           sizeof(UInt32), &audioCategory) != noErr) {
    return 1;
}
```

This stopped the feedback between mic and speaker on my hardware.